# Why is the output always [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, android, adb, node-webkit, node-modules

```
var dev = [device.id](or null);

function console(stdout){$('#console').text(stdout)}

function adbShell(command){
if(dev==null){throw Error('adb >No KFSOWI detected')}
client.shell(dev,command)
 .then(function(output){console(output)})
};
```

I am attempting to create a function to run an adb shell command, and return the output to the console, but the only return i am ever getting is [object Object]

Comment: I'm assuming output is an object, you may need to encapsulate it in `JSON.stringify();`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `"" + {}` - the stringification of any object which does not define `toString` - results in `"[object Object]"`. In this case the conversion to string likely happens in the `.text` function.

As suggested by meanIOstack, it *may* be meaningful to use `JSON.stringify` to create a "more useful" string. For instance;

```
function console (obj) {
   var str = typeof obj === "string" ? obj : JSON.stringify(obj)
   $('#console').text(str)
}
```

On the other hand the "real issue" may be that `output` does not evaluate to the expected value; at the very least the above function will give a better idea of *what* is being returned.

Comment: I wish i could say that worked. Same result. Ive had this issue before and solved it but dont remember how. I have managed to get a different result, but now its always null. Its probably worth mentioning that this issue is primarily with the adbkit node module

Comment: @KyleBerries If this produces the same result then the [ToString] happens early on before the call to console.. but apply the same approach; serialize the object [to JSON] *before* it is used as / implicitly converted to text so that it can be correctly represented as text.

Comment: Can you explain what causes this problem? Ive had the same problem in different scenarios. The above answer is probably a good explaination, but i dont understand it.   I.e. ""+{}

Comment: The default `[ToString]` ([as handled through `toString`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2)) for objects is very primitive and rarely useful. This [ToString], and thus `toString`, process is done in the case of `"" + anyObject`.